# How to get a word between two string in lua?

Tags: string, function, lua

I want to get a word between two string like this

```
local str = "Hello Stackoverflow guys"
```

Suppose the word between the two strings (Stackoverflow) is unknown and I want to get this.

Is there a function for this?

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question which results in invalidating an Answer, is against policy on Stack Overflow. Your edit here did so. The policy is that other users should proactively revert such changes. I have done so here. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use string patterns with captures for this.

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1

```
string.match("Hello Stackoverflow guys", "Hello (%a+) guys")
```

Returns any word of at least 1 letter that is between "Hello " and " guys".
In this case it's "Stackoverflow".

You can use different patterns of course to include numbers or other characters. Whatever you consider a word.

Of course it is also possible to get the second word without specifying "Hello " and " guys" or whatever. Just read the manual.

Comment: Actually i want to get a word between :
`<meta property="og:title" content="` and `">` in line 8

Comment: If it's not obvious how to replace "Hello " and " guys" with the strings you want to use, perhaps you need to review the linked documentation in more detail.

Comment: Look :

`   local source = http.request('https://t.me/joinchat/SomeThing')
`

Actually i want to get a word between :



`<meta property="og:title" content="`  and   `">` in line 8


what should i do with source.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the words, you can do

```
string.match("Hello Stackoverflow guys", "%s+(%S+)")
```

This finds the first run of whitespace and captures the following run of nonwhitespace characters.

Comment: Look :

`   local source = http.request('https://t.me/joinchat/SomeThing')
`

Actually i want to get a word between :



`<meta property="og:title" content="`  and   `">` in line 8


what should i do with source.

thanks

Comment: @Puryanms, it seems that it'd be better if you ask a separate question.