# How do I get a list of strings that are between 2 strings in Lua?

Tags: lua, html-parsing

I'm trying to write a HTML parser in Lua. A major roadblock I hit almost immediately was I have no idea how to get a list of strings between 2 strings. This is important for parsing HTML, where a tag is defined by being within 2 characters (or strings of length 1), namely '<' and '>'. I am aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49863367/13605488), but it only gets the *first occurence,* not *all instances* of a string between the 2 given strings.

What I mean by "list of strings between 2 strings" is something like this:

```
someFunc("<a b c> <c b a> a </c b a> </a b c>", "<", ">")
```

Returns:

```
{"a b c", "c b a", "/c b a", "/a b c"}
```

This does not have to parse newlines nor text in between tags, as both of those can be handled using extra logic. However, I would prefer it if it did parse newlines, so I can run the code once for the whole string returned by the first GET request.

Note: This is a experiment project to see if this is possible in the very limited Lua environment provided by the CC: Tweaked mod for Minecraft. Documentation here: https://tweaked.cc/

Comment: `for inner in html:gmatch"<(.-)>" do print(inner) end`

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply:

```lua
local list = {}
local html = [[<a href="">bla</a>]]
for innerTag in html:gmatch("<(.-)>") do
  list[#list] = innerTag
end
```

But be aware that it is weak as doesn't validade wrong things, as someone can put an `<` or `>` inside a string etc.